# How to get the first item in an array that doesn't match another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a preference list where the user selects a number of items from a list and they're then presented back to them in order of preference.

I've a prototype built, but I need some help with a feature I'd like to add. I want the user to see what preference the next item they select will be.

The behaviour would be:

- First the user is presented with "Choose your 1st preference"
- When they select their 1st preference this then changes to "Choose your 2nd preference, and so on.
- It'd also need to know if they'd deselected a preference and on doing so it'd need to say "Choose your 1st preference (or whatever preference)" again.

I've created a JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ygcL3ggb/)

I'm imagining to be able to use grep in some way to do this?

```
 var nextPreference = $.grep(preferencesAsText, function(v) {
      // return v !== First preference that isn't one of the preferences that are already selected
  });
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Edit: I've managed to get an array of the items that are in the list of chosen preferences by doing this:

```
var chosenPreferences = $('[data-schemeorder]').map(function() {
                        return $( this ).text();
                      })
                      .get();

  var arrayOfChosen = $.makeArray(chosenPreferences);

  console.log(arrayOfChosen);
```

So basically I just need a way of finding the first preference that isn't in this list, if that makes sense... [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygcL3ggb/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I think I've figured this one out. If you create an array of the chosen preferences and then use grep to create an array of the items that aren't in the preferences text, you can then use this to find the first item that is not selected.

```
var chosenPreferences = $('[data-schemeorder]').map(function() {
                        return $( this ).text();
                      })
                      .get();

  var arrayOfChosen = $.makeArray(chosenPreferences);
  var differenceArray = [],
      initialVal = 0;


  $.grep(preferencesAsText, function(el) {
    if($.inArray(el, arrayOfChosen) == -1) differenceArray.push(el);

    initialVal++;
  })

  if(differenceArray[0] === undefined) {
     $('#chosenLimit').show();
     $('#chooseYourPrefs').hide();
  } else {
    $('#chosenLimit').hide();
     $('#chooseYourPrefs').show();
     $('#chooseNextPreference').text(differenceArray[0]);
  }
```

And an updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ygcL3ggb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `schemePrefArray.length` to get the number of elements selected and display the text you need?

the text displayed would be `preferencesAsText[schemePrefArray.length]`

no?

Comment: The issue with that is if you deselect the 1st preference or anything out of sequence then it'd display the wrong text.